# Gmail Schema - button to confirm a double optin subscription

Tags: gmail, schema, subscription, confirmation

We want to add a 1click button to all the double optin email, we send on behalf of our clients to their optin subscriptions, which we require from them (our thousands of clients around the world with different languages).
We sign all email with DKIM and SPF, but we cannot register each from: address manually, so I wonder if you have a better idea on how to do this.
Thank you.